# how can I control the width of div containers for thumbnails?

Tags: html, css, width, thumbnails

I am unable to change the width of the columns that are containing the thumbnails below.  I want the container of the portrait images to be the size of the image the same way the container for the landscape images is equal to the image, so that there is no extra space between images.  Everything I try results in a different sized image without affecting the size of the container, which always equals the dimensions of the larger landscape image.  Can anyone help?  Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.center {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

/* Position the image container (needed to position the left and right arrows) */
.container {
  position: relative;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Add a pointer when hovering over the thumbnail images */
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* Container for image text */
.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 35px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    }

/* Six columns side by side */
.column {
  float: left;
  max-width: 10%;
}

    /* Add a transparency effect for thumnbail images */
.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

</style>

<body>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
                    <img src="img_144-109.JPG" style="height:80%" class="center">
                        </div>

            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
                    <img src="img_144-133.jpg" style="width:20%" class="center">
                        </div>

            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
                    <img src="img_free_admission.JPG" style="width:20%" class="center">
                        </div> 

            <div class="mySlides">
                <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
                    <img src="img_154-043.jpg" style="height:80%" class="center">
                        </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">❯</a>

  <div class="caption-container">
    <p id="caption"></p>
        </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.bartonlewisfilm.com/img_144-109.JPG" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="144-109, Dyckman St., IND Eighth Ave. Line">
                        </div>

                 <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.bartonlewisfilm.com/img_144-133.jpg" style="width:50%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="144-133, Dyckman St., IND Eighth Ave. Line">
                        </div>    

                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.bartonlewisfilm.com/img_free_admission.JPG" style="width:50%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="free admission, Greenpoint Ave., IND Crosstown Line">
                        </div> 

                <div class="column">
                    <img class="demo cursor" src="https://www.bartonlewisfilm.com/img_154-043.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="154-043, 116th St., IND Eighth Ave. Line">
                        </div>

            </div>
    </div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you remove all unnecessary code? Leave only the code that is important for your question.

Comment: There are two show stoppers with your question: **1.** Your not showing the images, therefore we do not know their dimensions, therefore we can't see what the code does. And **2.** You're not asking a question, nor are you describing what is the desired behavior/functionality.

Comment: I am too asking a question - not sure why it's not clear to you.  I want to make the size of the thumbnail containers for the smaller (portrait) images equal to the size of the image, as in the case of the landscape thumbnail.  As for the images not showing, when I ran the code snippet, I was able to see them.

Comment: The only code that was not needed for presenting the problem was that above the style tag, and I deleted it.